# Create scroll in one container based on the dynamic height of another container inside multiple nested flexboxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

**This is what I have:**

[image]

**This is what I want:**

[image]

So the whole content of 'Container 5' should be visible without scroll. The height of 'Container 2' should be only dependent on the height of 'Container 5'. 'Container 4' should be scrollable if it has more content than 'Container 5'. **The content of 'Container 5' is dynamic - I don't know it's height.** 'Container 3' should fulfill the whole available screen space at the bottom.

**`This is code:`**
https://jsfiddle.net/antonfil/5kd1gnou/13/

[image]

Any ideas how to do it?

**JavaScript solutions are fine but it's also interesting if it is possible to achieve it with pure CSS.**

Comment: How is container 4 supposed to know the height of container 5?

Comment: And the `overflow` property requires a fixed length (i.e., something to overflow). Without a defined height limitation, what would be the overflow trigger for container 4?

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin so it's impossible without setting fixed heights?

Comment: A scrollbar can only be generated when an overflow is triggered. With dynamic heights, the boxes just expand and contract to accommodate the content. Somewhere along the line you need a fixed length.

Comment: I'm speaking above in terms of pure CSS. Of course, if you are open to JS then the solution is simple.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin sure I would of course prefer pure CSS solution. For me it is still interesting if it is theoretically possible to achieve with pure CSS.

Answer (score 4):

change style of `container-2`,`container-4` and `container-5` as below.

```
#container-4 {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y:auto;
  flex: 1 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#container-5 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0;
  height:min-content;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

here we set the height of `container-5` as the minimum height. And set a vertical overflow as `scroll` for `container-4`. Then adjust the height of `container-4` dynamically using Jquery.

add this script to your HTML file.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    let height=$("#container-5").height();
   $("#container-4").height(height);
});
</script>
```

And don't forget to add Jquery to your HTML.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't set fixed height (height:100px;) to container-4. It can be more or less - it's content is dynamic.

Comment: Then please add jquery to set the height dynamically. I edited my answer. Hope It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

add this script

```
  <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const container_5 = document.querySelector('#container-5');
            const container_4 = document.querySelector('#container-4');
            container_4.style.height = container_5.offsetHeight + 'px';
        });
    </script>
```

and change `#container-4` css to:

```
#container-4 {
    display: flex;
    height: 0;
    flex: 1 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

the script above will set the height of `#container-4` to the calculated height of `#container-5`.
by doing this you don't need a 'predefined' size for any of the containers.

Answer (score -1):

To container 2, try to add `overflow: scroll;`.

Comment: everything is not so simple here :)